# Solaris 10 IPMP and zones

Tags: networking, solaris, ip, solaris-zones

Is there a way to have an IPMP group Virtual IP only be assigned to a none global zone ?

The reason I ask is the need to reduce the number of IP addresses, as we only have so many spare.

If I have an IPMP group in my global zone and then wish to use that IPMP group in a none global zone- I believe I need 4 IP addresses , 3 for the GZ and 1 for the NGZ.

Is there any way I can use IPMP in a NGZ using just the 3 IP addresses ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use testadresses for IPMP, you can use IPMPs link failure detection.

**Example for host testhost**

hostname.bge0:
`testhost group production`

hostname.bge1:
`group production`

This configures just one IP to bge0, but if bge0 fails, the IPs fails over to bge1.

You may assign a dedicated device to the zone via  `add device` entry in the zone configururation but I did never test if this works for network devices, too.

Comment: I agree with jmk, but you may need/want to add the -failover or failover options for the physical interfaces to ensure the IPs failover, but not the physical interface.
In the above example by jmk, add `-failover` to bge1's hostname file on the global.

`if_mpadm` is a really useful tool for testing that IPMP is working as you expect it (without a manual cable pull).